# Why aren't these 2 codes running equally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I am working with MapBox and React and I am trying to understand why these codes run in different order...

1) I create a separate function to be called from componentDidMount and code runs line by line (I get the console logs in order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

```
  componentDidMount() {
   console.log(1);
   let mapOptions = {
     container: this.mapContainer,
     style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
     center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
     zoom: this.state.zoom
   }
   console.log(2);

   if( "geolocation" in navigator){
     console.log(3);
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
       console.log(4);
       const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords
       const coordinates = [longitude,latitude]
       console.log(5);
       mapOptions.center = coordinates
       console.log(6);
       this.createMap(mapOptions)
     })
   }
 }

 createMap(mapOptions){
   console.log(7);
   const map = new mapboxgl.Map(mapOptions);
 }
```

2) I call the createMap function in componentDidMount and have all the code inside that function and code runs in a different order: 1,2,3,7,4,5,6

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createMap()
  }

  createMap(){
    console.log(1);
    let mapOptions = {
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom
    }
    console.log(2);

    if( "geolocation" in navigator){
      console.log(3);
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(4);
        const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords
        const coordinates = [longitude,latitude]
        console.log(5);
        mapOptions.center = coordinates
        console.log(6);
      })
    }

    console.log(7);
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map(mapOptions);

  }
```

Comment: make the createMap() function async and add await at navigation.geolocation.getCurrentPosition call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is async call.

**1. Code Snippet 1st:**

Console logs from 4 to 7 called inside the resolved promise.

**2. Code Snippet 2**

Method `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns promise and things continue as is. Hence you see `console.log(7)` running first. Once the promise resolves, then rest of the code runs.

Hope it helps.